# How to draw a finite-duration sequence

Tags: discrete-signals

On page $359$ of the 2nd edition of the book "Signals & Systems", by Oppenheim and Willsky, the authors wrote the following words:

"Consider a general sequence $x[n]$ that is of finite duration. That is, for some integers $N1$ and $N2$, $x[n] = 0$ outside the range $-N1\leq n\leq N2$. A signal of this type is illustrated in $\text{Figure}\; 5.1\:(\text{a})$"

[image]

My three questions are:

1. Regarding $x[n]$ in the figure, do the leading and trailing zero-valued samples exist?
2. If the leading and trailing zero-valued samples exist, then what is the duration of (how many samples are in) the finite-duration $x[n]$ sequence?
3. If the leading and trailing zero-valued samples do not exist, then why are they shown in $\text{Figure}\; 5.1\:(\text{a})?$

Comment: Perhaps "duration" is not the best word to choose when the reader (such as the OP) can imagine a signal that has a finite domain. The authors could have introduced the term [_support_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) for the set on which the signal is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

The plot as shown makes sense as nothing has limited the time axis to be going from $-\infty$ to +$\infty$. So we are showing the finite duration sequence as it would appear on such a time axis.

We can limit the time axis to a finite number of samples as used in the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) or the an unlimited time axis as used in the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT). Neither approach would change the number of samples in a finite duration signal.

So the plot and text is implying the time axis extends from  $-\infty$ to +$\infty$. The number of samples in the finite duration sequence would be the non-zero samples.

My confusion when first answering this question was the case of the DFT and how adding zeros is significant to the result, but really this is just approximating the DTFT and not changing the duration of the sequence itself.

Comment: @ Dan Boschen. Can you tell me what is your answer to Question {2}?

Comment: I thought I did; all the samples are included

Comment: @ Dan Boschen. The answer to Question {2} must be an integer number. What do you think is that number?

Comment: I am confused by your question— Simply count the samples you see— how many do you count?

Comment: You must be confused by my answer or I am confused by your question? There are an integer number of samples in your plot, so simply count them. It’s trivial.

Comment: @ Dan Boschen. The quote at the beginning of my question states that when n = 1000 then sample x[1000] = 0. And you believe sample x[1000] exists. If x[1000] exists then how many samples are in the x[n] sequence?

Comment: I don’t see that in your question. The length of the sequence has to  be defined somewhere. But I think I see your confusion as it is implying that your sequences beyond the length x[n]=0 and I would not agree with that. A finite length sequence can have zeros pretended and appended which would absolutely be included in the length

Comment: So I agree with your point of confusion and that the text itself is confusing and misstated.

Comment: But in thinking about it further a finite duration impulse response of length N could be plotted out on a time axis of length N+1000 and it would have 1000 zeros but that wouldn’t change the finite duration of the impulse response (better called the unit sample response)—— so i am rethinking my answer

Comment: I completely changed my answer

Comment: @ Dan Boschen. Thanks for your time. I'm trying to understand your changed answer. Are you saying the sequences x1 = [0,1,2,3,4,0] and  x2 = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0] have equal durations?

Comment: @knight no I would say the duration of those sequences, the way you defined them would be 6 and 10 of course.  Now consider this; if we put an underline under the first element (which designates n =0) and then wanted to see what x1 looked like over time (sample time) starting with n =0, it would look like this: 0,1,2,3,4,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.....  Do you agree?

Comment: I think the point is, the figure you copied is showing what a finite duration sequence looks like over all time. (n is going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.)

Comment: @ Dan Boschen. No. I do not agree that my finite duration 6-sample x1 = [0,1,2,3,4,0] contains an infinite number of zero-valued samples. If x1 contained an infinite number of zero-valued samples then it would be an infinite duration sequence.

Comment: @knight  Yes I see the confusion and we need to be careful with the terminology. The authors are defining their use clearly and I don't see an issue with it:  Consider FIR filters specifically; they have a Finite Impulse Response (unit sample response)--- we can evaluate the unit sample response over all time and the trailing zeros are trivial-- If we plotted 1000 or 10000 samples of the unit sample response that itself of finite duration for 20 samples, the result would not change: the duration of the sample response would be 20 samples and the rest of the samples would be zero.

Comment: @knight there is nothing that limits us from comparing multiple sequences of finite duration on the same time axis. To do that we say that any samples beyond the duration of the sequence are equal to 0. I see your point that not existing at all would seem more valid-- such as the height of a wood block versus distance along the stick's length; it would equally seem confusing to say the height of the stick =0 beyond the length of the stick (the stick simply doesn't exist there.

Comment: @knight But this is a perfectly reasonable and valid mathematical description. Consider the same description for a continuous time signal that is limited in time;  $x(t) = 0$ for $ t> t_o$ is an accurate description of that process.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want the zero padding to exist, it exists.  if you don't want those samples to exist as zero, you must define what they are.  the most common alternative is that outside the interval $-N_1 \ge n \ge N_2$ is to periodically extend the the sequence.
2. $N_1 + N_2 +1$
3. they're shown as existing because whomever made that illustration intends them to exist and for them to equal zero.

if you define: $N \triangleq N_1 + N_2 +1$ and impose periodicity

$$ x[n+N] = x[n] \qquad \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

then the DFT is a mapping of one periodic function (with a finite period) to another periodic function having the same period $N$.

$$ X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{n_0+N} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi nk/N} \qquad \qquad n_0 \in \mathbb{Z} $$

you are allowed to set $n_0 = -N_1$ and the upper limit becomes $N_2$.

If, instead, you define it as

$$ x[n] = 0 \qquad \qquad \text{for} \ n<-N_1 \ \text{or} \ n>N_2 $$

then the DTFT is

$$\begin{align}
 X \big( e^{j\omega} \big) &\triangleq \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{n_0+N} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} \qquad \qquad n_0 = -N_1 \\
\end{align} $$

Now it turns out that the two are equal when $ \omega = 2 \pi k / N $.